# Android: How to restore List data when pressing the "back" button?

Tags: android, android-activity

My question is about restoring complex activity related data when coming back to the activity using the "back" button".
Activity A has a ListView which is connected to ArrayAdapter serving as its data source - this happens in onCreate().

1. By default, if I move to activity B and press "back" to get back to activity A, does my list stay intact with all the data or do I just get visual "copy" of the screen but the data is lost?
2. What can I do when more than activities are involved? Let's say activity A starts activity B which starts activity C and then I press "back" twice to get to A. How do I ensure the integrity of the A's data when it gets back to the foreground? PrefsManager does not seem to handle complex object very intuitively.

Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Activity A has a ListView which is
>   connected to ArrayAdapter serving as
>   its data source

Note that an `ArrayAdapter` is not a persistent store.

> By default, if I move to activity B
>   and press "back" to get back to
>   activity A, does my list stay intact
>   with all the data or do I just get
>   visual "copy" of the screen but the
>   data is lost?

That depends.

Typically, `Activity` A has not gone anywhere. However, if the user leaves the app for an extended period, Android may destroy `Activity` A, leaving a placeholder in the activity stack, to free up memory. If, later, the user presses BACK, Android will re-create `Activity` A. You need to hang onto your data in this case, either by using a persistent store (file, database, etc.) or by using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

You can find more in the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) section of the Activity class description.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actively `finish()` Activity A when you start Activity B, its data and state will all be present when you return to it, regardless of how many activities you stack up.

Comment: That is not necessarily true. Android may elect to destroy the activity to free up RAM for other processing.